# port 8080 is already in use and no process using 8080 has been listed

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to start Tomcat from Eclipse, but a problem occured:

> Port 8080 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I tried to list processes connected to this port using command on Windows:

```
netstat -aon
```

But on the listing there is no process with `PID = 8080`. I also tried:

```
netstat -aon | find "8080"
```

But it also didn't find anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may have accidentially launched Tomcat twice.  Only the first one can use the port.  Others are denied in the way you see.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PID is the process ID - not the port number. You need to look for an entry with ":8080" at the end of the address/port part (the second column). Then you can look at the PID and use Task Manager to work out which process is involved... or run `netstat -abn` which will show the process names (but must be run under an administrator account).

Having said that, I *would* expect the `find "8080"` to find it...

Another thing to do is just visit `http://localhost:8080` - on that port, chances are it's a web server of some description.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is helpful - I found it .

Comment: +1 I found theat option "b" not present so I repleaced with p so netstat -anp | grep 8080 will help, thank you

Comment: In my case, visiting http://localhost:8080 showed me that jenkins server is running on my mac. Changed the port for jenkins as mentioned here by @alex - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139338/change-jenkins-port-on-macos

Answer (score 5):

Open eclipse go to Servers panel, right click or press <kbd>F3</kbd> to open Overview window and go to Ports (Modify the server ports). You will get the following:

```
tomcat adminport
HTTP/1.1
AJP/1.3
```

You can change the port numbers (e.g. HTTP/1.1 port number 8080 to 8082).

Answer (score 3):

In windows " **wmic process where processid="pid of the process running" get commandline** "  worked for me. The 
culprit was **wrapper.exe** process of **webhuddle** jboss soft.

Answer (score 1):

If no other process is using the port 8080, Eventhough eclipse shows the port 8080 is used while starting the server in eclipse, first you have to stop the server by hitting the stop button in "Configure Tomcat"(which you can find in your start menu under tomcat folder), then try to start the server in eclipse then it will be started.

If any other process is using the port 8080 and as well as you no need to disturb it. then you can change the port.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a conflict with the virtualization function of Windows 10. This problem occurred after installing Hyper-V, virtual machine platform, and hypervisor platform to use hyper-v, docker, and bluestack together.
Even if I check with netstat, it is not a port in use, and even if I restart Windows and change the port, it does not start up saying that it is in use for all ports.
So, by changing the following services to Disabled in Windows Services, the Tomcat problem was solved, but bluestack, docker, etc. execution became impossible.
After starting Tomcat, when I manually changed the services again, bluestack was executed.

```
Hyper-V Host Compute Service
HV Host Service
Host network service
Network virtualization service
```