# Jboss Server Error:Server already running on localhost

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, java-6

I am working on web project where jboss application server is required. After configured the jboss server, I was running my application. It is showing error like:Server already running on local host.Web found a running server at URL //localhost:8080.[image]

Comment: Just check if another instance of the server is already running at 8080 using Task Manager.

Comment: In Windows, open the task manager, and kill the java process (probably the one using most memory).

Comment: In my case, visiting http://localhost:8080 showed me that jenkins server is running on my mac. Changed the port for jenkins as mentioned here by @alex - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139338/change-jenkins-port-on-macos

Answer (score 20):

Works for me

- Open Command Prompt
- Type `netstat -noa` and hit Enter
- Check the "PID" of process that uses your port
- And type `taskkill /PID "PID number"` and hit Enter

*As @Mxsky stated: You may have to force the processus to quit with the /F option.So the command becomes: `taskkill /PID pid_number /F`*

- Done. Now start the server

Comment: I've find out that Skype is using port 80 and 443. Maybe it causes the error.

Comment: You may have to force the processus to quit with the `/F` option.So the command becomes: `taskkill /PID pid_number /F`

Answer (score 13):

Generally this issue happen because of proxy setting. If none of the process running on 8080 port and still you find this error then reason is proxy server is not bypass for local address.

Bypass Proxy Server for Local Address by below Setting on IE.

**Open IE, Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Setting -> Check mark on checkbox "Bypass proxy server for local address"**

Now restart your jboss server.

Comment: Thanks, I had done the bypass at system level but in my case, I had to go to Window-> Preferences-> Network Connections and then set 'Active Provider' to 'Manual' and provide proxy entries and also provide 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' as 'Proxy bypass'. I am running Eclipse Oxygen on Ubunutu 16.04

Answer (score 6):

If this happened from not closing eclipse properly (or it just crashed):

- When it is closed, 'End Process Tree' on `javaw.exe` with task manager.
- Restart eclipse.

This is not likely the best way but it works... or did for me at least.

If this is from another server running:

- You need to make sure you have separate port numbers per server instance.
- Otherwise it will not bind correctly; or at all.

Answer (score 1):

What Süleyman Şahin said was right. 
Open Command Prompt
Type netstat -noa and hit Enter
Check the "PID" of process that uses your port
And type taskkill /PID "PID number" and hit Enter
As @Mxsky stated: You may have to force the processus to quit with the /F option.So the command becomes: taskkill /PID pid_number /F

However, if you are unable to kill the process in the cmd, check for the PID that is using port 8080. In the command prompt, [::]8080 it will look like this.
Now, goto the Task Manager in the Details tab check for the PID and right click on the name of the service and click Go to service(s). Now stop that service that is using port 8080.

Now, open the eclipse and start the JBoss. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by changing the port number in my server and then changing the port number in standalone-full.xml too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appear something due to bad configuration. You have made some change in the standalone.xml file and the server doesn't start again. You can check that by try to launch the server from cmd. if it's so, just check you config. otherwise try the approach of @ECleveland

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after opening cmd in **Administrator mode**:

1. First open the cmd in **administrator mode**.
2. Find the PID number for port 8080 by using this command:

   `netstat -ano | findstr :8080`

   Output will like: 
     `TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3951`
3. Kill the PID (pidnumber is 3951 from above output. Your pidnumber is different)

   `taskkill/pid pidnumber`

   Output will like: 
   `ERROR: The process with PID 3952 could not be terminated.`
   `Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option)`
4. If it shows ERROR then use below command:

   `taskkill/pid pidnumber /F`

Output: `SUCCESS: The process with PID 3952 has been terminated.`

Example: [Image Contains the above steps with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL61q.png)