# An application server may already be running on host localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm working on a web project where JBoss Application Server is used for deployment. I'm getting the below message once I start the server.

> An application server may already be running on host localhost
>
> Web Poller found a running server at url http://localhost:8080

I couldn't find any entries on `netstat` command on process which uses port `8080`.

Tried the solution mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403012/jboss-server-errorserver-already-running-on-localhost) as well.

Comment: Here are working and detailled answers for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403012/jboss-server-errorserver-already-running-on-localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Linux**

Try below

```
 ps -ef|grep jboss
```

now if jboss running it will return `pid` take that `pid`  and run below command

```
kill -9 pid
```

**For Windows**

```
ALT+CTRL+DELETE
```

and start task manager & then search for `javaw.exe` service and close it

Comment: Notice the `windows` tag.

Comment: javaw.exe is not in the running services list

Comment: then try to kill `java.exe` server wont work if jvm is not running

Comment: java.exe entry is also not there.

Comment: Did u run server standalone or with some `IDE` ? And `IDE` crashed or down and server was running is this the scenario for you?

Comment: I hope so. I tried running the server from eclipse. But I didn't have a problem of crashing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83730/discussion-between-k-nash-and-subodh-joshi).

Comment: Never use `kill -9 pid` unless `kill pid`  `kill -term pid` or `kill -15 pid` (all of which are equivalent) does not work. `kill -9` pulls the rug out from under your application (perhaps leaving your database or other resource in an inconsistent state) whereas the other options tell the process to commence an orderly shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The Port is under listenning by a JVM, you should look for the entries of JVM in the result of your netstat command.

Comment: Please explain how the OP can do what you have described. You basically said "If you want to sit, build a chair" without explaining what a chair is, or how to build one.