# How to access / share Jenkins from another computer?

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins (localhost:8080) on RHEL and I am able to build code successfully

Now, I want to setup master / slave agent.

My laptop will act as 'Master Jenkins' and my colleague's will be 'Slave'

However, my colleague could not connect to 'Master Jenkins' and we both are on SAME LAN and able to ping each other

I tried the following but nothing worked

```
(a)  Changed --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0
(b)  Changed --httpListenAddress=<my laptop ip>
(c)  Changed --httpListenAddress=<my colleague's laptop ip>
```

and my colleague tried `'telnet <my laptop ip> 8080'` from his laptop and did not work

Please help me to resolve this issue and I am new to Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by adding the port no '8080' in firewall

Goto 'Computer --> More Applications (or) Control Center --> Firewall --> Other Ports --> Add'

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins should host it's own service, so that is probably not the problem. Is your firewall open on port 8080?

Comment: I tried 'netstat -ant | grep 8080' and the output was nothing, so I guess port is open.  'telnet' results in 'connection time out.  'tcpdump -i eth0 8080' shows some trace when I do 'telnet' but could not figure out the error

Comment: And 'nc ipaddress 8080 < /dev/null; echo $?' returned '1' and I hope port is closed

Comment: 'nmap -sS -O 127.0.0.1' clearly indicated that the port is not open

Answer (score 1):

For all Mac Users. None of the above worked for me I installed Jenkins using HomeBrew.

go to

~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist

and Change the httpListenAddress value from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

Since this homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist file in placed in LaunchAgents you need to restart your machine to make this effective.

Comment: If Jenkins is installed via brew, this file is not the original.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139338/change-jenkins-port-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

Open the POrt 8080 via firewall and then change the URL of jenkins from "Manage Jenkins>Config Sys>Jenkins Location>" to "http://yourIP:8080" and then access it from other machine on same network domain.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, after upgrading the local Java instance, Jenkins was no longer accessible over the domain.  The fix was to update the path to the new java.exe, in the Programs and Services tab, in the Properties of the Jenkins rule, in Windows Firewall Advanced settings.  You may also use the "All programs that meet the specified conditions" setting, but I do not know the impact that choice would have on the security of the server.