# How to run multiple Jenkins server with different ports on the same Mac Machine?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using macOS BigSur and I want to run 2 Jenkins server with different ports on it. I downloaded Jenkins using homebrew. Is there a way for it? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in the jenkins.xml file and change that port, for more info see, dpends on how do you launch jenkins:

- [How to change port for jenkins window service when 8080 is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769478/how-to-change-port-for-jenkins-window-service-when-8080-is-being-used/44020922)
- [How to start jenkins on different port rather than 8080 using command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265277/how-to-start-jenkins-on-different-port-rather-than-8080-using-command-prompt-in)
- [Change Jenkins port on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139338/change-jenkins-port-on-macos)

Comment: okay, I understand how to change the port now, what about having multiple Jenkins CI servers on one machine, how to go about that?\

Comment: depends on how do you run jenkins (as service, by command line,etc.. ) just copy the folder or create new instances on different ports